# Is there way to click multiple checkboxes when a option(check box) is on and when it is off you can only select one at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I want to be able to perform the functionality in the picture above. It wont work however.

[image]

```js
$("#customSwitches").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.data('clicked')) {
    alert("not element clicked");
    $this.data('clicked', false);
    $(document).on('click', "#radio1, #radio2, #radio3, #radio4").not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
  } else {
    alert("element clicked");
    $this.data('clicked', true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each click of the check box from the groups, you can checked the `checked` property of `#customSwitches`. If it is not checked then you can count the length of `checked` check boxes from the group, if it is more than `1` then you can prevent the default event.

When clicking `#customSwitches` you can reset all the check boxes from the group.

You can try the following way:

```js
$(".vehicle").click(function(e){
    if($('#customSwitches').is(':not(:checked)')){
      if($('.vehicle:checked').length > 1){
        alert('You can not check multiple');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
});

$("#customSwitches").click(function(e){
   $(".vehicle").prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="customSwitches"> Select Multiple</label><input type="checkbox" id="customSwitches">
<hr/>

<input class="vehicle" type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label>
<input class="vehicle" type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label>
<input class="vehicle" type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label>
```

Comment: Any reason you felt the need to add another answer with the same logic?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, may be the logic is same but the implementation is not.

Comment: I have this code in the componentDidMount is that where it is suppose to be as it is still not working for me with your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has some syntax issues and uses nested event handlers, which is not a good design pattern.

In basic terms you are trying to build a dynamic checkbox limiter based on the first checkbox state. To do that simply determine if the first box is checked, and then count the number of checked regions to see if it exceeds the limit. If so, disallow the current box to be checked. Try this:

```js
let $allowMulti = $('#allow_multi').on('change', function() {
  if (!this.checked)
    $('.region').prop('checked', false); // remove all checks if no multi allowed
});

$('.region').on('change', function() {
  let selectedCount = $('.region:checked').length;
  if (!$allowMulti.prop('checked') && selectedCount > 1)
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="allow_multi"> 
    Select multiple regions
  </label>
</p>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="region" value="1"> 1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="region" value="2"> 2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="region" value="3"> 3
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="region" value="4"> 4
</label>
```

Comment: Is it necessary for the <span> around each input and for the checkbox's to have values?

Comment: The labels aren't necessary, I just added them as they're good practice and make the hit area bigger (it means you can click the number to check the box as well as the box itself). The checkboxes should have values, though. Especially if you're sending the data to the server.

Comment: also ive the above code snippet in componentDidMount() will this make a difference, as it is still not working

Comment: I've never used React so I can't help you there. It'd be worth starting a new question if you're stuck